# Is there a way that I can place a watermark on the right bottom of multiple images, no matter what dimension the images are?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there any way that I can place a watermark on the right bottom of multiple images, no matter what dimension the images are? I have tried using Photoshop Scripts > image processor, but it works only for images of same dimension. I want to put watermark on multiple images of different dimensions. This is the output i got.

For the first image the watermark got placed correctly, but for the second image watermark got distracted. As you can clearly see the dimensions are different. Please suggest me some solution.

thanks in advance :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry Joonas it dosent answer my question of "watermarking multiple images of different dimensions in photoshop". I know how to watermark multiple images of same dimension in photoshop. Thanks anyways

Comment: Your question is most definitely a duplicate, different size images or not.

Comment: Yeah i agree that this type of question has been asked and i have went through it. But i don't get my answer to my question there. I wish someone could help me.

Comment: ...or is the photoshop answer just too vague for you to understand? Cause the way I read it, it's not restricted to one specific image size, it's just difficult to follow if you aren't very experienced with photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

Use a batch converter. One that is free and I know for sure that adds watermarks is FastStone Photo Resizer. You can download it here:

http://download.cnet.com/FastStone-Photo-Resizer/3000-2192_4-10319476.html

In Advanced Options you can find the Watermark feature with X, Y position (by corner), Opacity and much more. Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Komental for the link. I wanted to know whether we can do this in Photoshop???

Comment: @Aby I think you can run batch Actions but I am not sure if you can make it.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3nu5o09wI0 i got this video.....this was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this in Photoshop. This will push to bottom right of any image, even if the watermark is bigger than the image.

BUT, you will need to learn to record Actions. These are the best feature of Photoshop, BY FAR, so well worth the time. It's kind of like programming your old VCR (or TiVo).

Make an Action that opens each image from a given folder (put all your images in one folder to make this easier), then imports the layer of your Watermark artwork, and then selects both the image and the watermark.

// To make this faster, preload your watermark image as an open file, and have the Action import that, so that is doesn't have to actually load and then import the watermark for each image, only duplicate it to your new image.

Now you can align right and bottom edges of both layers. You need to select both your layers (the image and the watermark) first, so that the Layer>Align functions become available. See image for where these functions are.

Use Align Right Edges and Align Bottom Edges.

...it will be roughly where you want... but might be jammed up against an edge.

So you'll have to pad your Watermark artwork sufficiently to get it to sit where you want. Or add a couple of nudges/moves of the artwork up and to the left into the Action after it's Aligned the Watermark to bottom right.

[image: Layer Align Functions]